# String concatenation issues

Tags: php

I'm trying to concatenate this string but I know i'm going wrong somewhere.

Can anyone see the problem?

```
("."txt("LANG_100000DELIVEREDORDER","100,000th delivered order!")."", "", "");
```

Original: `("100,000th delivered order!", "", "");`

Thanks

Comment: `"(".txt(...).', "", "", "")'` ?

Comment: You should be getting *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'txt' (T_STRING)*. You need to configure PHP to display errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would want:

```
(txt("LANG_100000DELIVEREDORDER","100,000th delivered order!"), "", "");
```

Comment: Cheers, been staring at this problem for 15 minutes, i knew it would be ridiculously simple.